# Clearing (banning) the [clear] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-block-request

Someone asked a question about an old DOS function that clears a text window called `CLS`, and tagged it [cls](/questions/tagged/cls).  I thought that was an odd tag to have, and it turned out that most cases of this tag were related to [cls-compliant](/questions/tagged/cls-compliant).  There weren't that many of these tagged "cls", so I retagged the appropriate ones.

That left me wondering what tag--if any--should be for questions about clearing the terminal.  It seemed to me that using the word "clear" in the question and then using [console](/questions/tagged/console) is the better umbrella.  But this led me to discover [clear](/questions/tagged/clear).  That has a random smattering of uses like:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947810/ie-not-clearing-attribute-after-2nd-call-of-function
- [clear/truncate file in C when already open in "r+" mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981018/clear-truncate-file-in-c-when-already-open-in-r-mode)
- [How do I clear the cache and cookies for an embedded Chromium browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269587/how-do-i-clear-the-cache-and-cookies-for-an-embedded-chromium-browser)

I'd suggest wiping out this tag and banning it from being recreated.  It basically seems to mean *"I used the word clear in my post somewhere"* and has no greater taxonomy or browsing knowledge.

*(By contrast, what I like about tags like "caching" and "cookies" is that someone else might come in and add them to a question later, in which the original poster didn't know the terms...or their relevance to that issue in their question.  I can't see adding the tag "clear" to something after the fact and feeling I'd done useful work.)*